# How do I configure Azure SignalR with Blazor Server-Side?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

Developing a Blazor server-side application
The app cannot have downtime, so even if one of the web-app instances recycles, connectivity must remain solid.  Thus, I am trying to channel SignalR communication  from server-side Blazor to the client thru Azure SignalR service, rather than specific WebApp instance.

Where in the Blazor project, do I specify my own Azure SignalR service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Azure:SignalR:ConnectionString` is the default configuration key that SignalR looks for to establish a connection.

You can set the value of this key with the following command.

```
dotnet user-secrets set Azure:SignalR:ConnectionString "<your connection string>"
```

Also do not forget to add AzureSignalR service in your startup file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();
    ...
}
```

For more information, you can check the [aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/master/samples/ServerSideBlazor) repository.